# memcpy for specific byteorder c/c++

Tags: c++, buffer, memcpy

1) I have a big buffer
2) I have a lot of variables of almost every types,

I use this buffer to send to multiple destinations, with different byte orders.

when I send to a network byte order, I usually used htons, or htonl and a customized function for specific data types,

so my issue,

every time I am constructing the buffer, I change byte order for each variable then use memcpy.

however, does anyone know a better way, like I was wishing for an efficient memcpy with specific intended byte order

an example,

```
UINT32 dwordData = 0x01234567;
UINT32 dwordTmp = htonl(dwordData);
memcpy(&buffer[loc], &dwordTmp, sizeof(UNIT32));
loc += sizeof(UNIT32);
```

this is just an example I just randomly wrote btw

I hope for a function that look like

```
memcpyToNetwork(&buffer[loc], &dwordTmp, sizeof(UNIT32));
```

if you know what I mean, naming is just a descriptive, and depending on the data type it does the byte order for the specific data type so I dont have to keep changing orders manually and have a temp variable to copy to, saving copying twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard solution, but it is fairly easy to write yourself.

Off the top of my head, an outline could look like this:

```
// Macro to be able to switch easily between encodings. Just for convenience
#define WriteBuffer WriteBufferBE 

// Generic template as interface specification. Not implemented itself
// Takes buffer (of sufficient size) and value, returns number of bytes written
template <typename T>
size_t WriteBufferBE(char* buffer, const T& value);

template <typename T>
size_t WriteBufferLE(char* buffer, const T& value);

// Specializations for specific types
template <>
size_t WriteBufferBE(char* buffer, const UINT32& value)
{
    buffer[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
    buffer[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    buffer[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    buffer[3] = (value) & 0xFF;
    return 4;
}

template <>
size_t WriteBufferBE(char* buffer, const UINT16& value)
{
    buffer[0] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    buffer[1] = (value) & 0xFF;
    return 2;
}

template <>
size_t WriteBufferLE(char* buffer, const UINT32& value)
{
    buffer[0] = (value) & 0xFF;
    buffer[1] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    buffer[2] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    buffer[3] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
    return 4;
}

template <>
size_t WriteBufferLE(char* buffer, const UINT16& value)
{
    buffer[0] = (value) & 0xFF;
    buffer[1] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    return 2;
}

// Other types left as an exercise. Can use the existing functions!

// Usage:
loc += writeBuffer(&buffer[loc], dwordData);
```

Comment: I like this one because it saved a function call with big Endian write, also I have a similar function for reading from the buffer :-)

Comment: do you know if calling this made function cost as much as calling a memcpy by any chance.

Comment: @abdul: They should perform equivalent to memcpy. They can easily be inlined by the compiler and their implementation pattern is used often enough that most optimisers recognize it and produce the most efficient code possible (sometimes even merging a sequence of byte-moves to a (d)word move).